# JQuery in Angular Directive not wroking

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an node/angular app which is pretty simple. The problem i'm having is getting my jQuery to work inside my directive. I created a directive that uses quite a bit of jQuery inside its link function. When the website is first loaded in the browser the directive works perfectly. However when I go to another partial and then click the browsers back button the jQuery in the directive no longer works. The directive is firing properly as I've tested this out with alerts and console.log statements. I've even tested regular javascript and it works after I go to another partial and then come back to the first partial. I'm not sure why the jQuery isn't working in this instance but I really need help figuring this out. The jQuery file is loaded in the index.html file along with the other scripts and stylesheets.

Index.html:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<base href='/'>
<title>MobiMall</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body style="background-color: transparent; margin: 0">
    <ng-view></ng-view>

<script src="js/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

partial/index.html

```
<div id="phone-wrap" swipe-clothes>
  <div id="mobi-phone" class="col-sm-6">
    <div id="mobi-phone-container">
        <div id="mobi-phone-window">
            <div id="mobi-cards-top">
            <ul id="mobi-cards-header" class="list-unstyled">

            </ul>       
        </div>
        <div id="mobi-cards" class="list-unstyled">
            <ul id="mobi-cards-swipe" class="list-unstyled" style="display: block">

            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="mobi-cards-bottom">
            <a id="mobi-cards-hanger"></a>
            <a id="mobi-cards-star"></a>
            <a id="mobi-cards-bag"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', []).
directive('swipeClothes', function($rootScope) {
var Person = {
  wrap: $('#mobi-cards-swipe'),
  topWrap: $('#mobi-cards-header'),
  clothing: [ 
    {img: "/images/clothingImage1.png",
             name:"Brian",
             image:"/images/profilepic1.png"
            },
    {img: "/images/clothingImage2.png",
             name:"Brian",
             image:"/images/profilepic1.png"
            },
    {img: "/images/clothingImage3.png",
             name:"Jennifer",
             image:"/images/profilepic2.png"
            },
],
  add: function(index){
    var random = this.clothing[index];//this.clothing[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.clothing.length)];
    this.topWrap.append("<li style='-webkit-transition: all .3s linear; transition: all .3s linear;'><figure><img src='"+ random.image +"'/></figure><p>"+ random.name +"</p></li>"),
    this.wrap.append("<li style='-webkit-transition: all .8s ease-out; transition: all .8s ease-out;' id='mobi-card'><div id='mobi-card-overlay'></div><figure><img src='"+ random.img +"'/></figure></li>");
  },

  addFront: function(index){
    var random = this.clothing[index];//this.clothing[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.clothing.length)];
    this.topWrap.prepend("<li style='-webkit-transition: all .3s linear; transition: all .3s linear;'><figure><img src='"+ random.image +"'/></figure><p>"+ random.name +"</p></li>"),
    this.wrap.prepend("<li style='-webkit-transition: all .8s ease-out; transition: all .8s ease-out;' id='mobi-card'><div id='mobi-card-overlay'></div><figure><img src='"+ random.img +"'/></figure></li>");
  }
};

var index = 0,
    animationEndEvent = "webkitTransitionEnd mozTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd otransitionend transitionend",
    choose = true;

function add(){

  var list = $('#mobi-cards-swipe li'),
          length = list.length,
          header = $('#mobi-cards-header li'),
          headerLength = header.length;

  if (length > 3) {
    list.eq(0).remove();
  }
  if (headerLength > 3) {
   header.eq(0).remove();
  }
  if (index > 2) {
    index = 0;
  }
  Person.addFront(index);
  animateMobi();
}

function animateMobi(){

  setTimeout(function(){
    var list = $('#mobi-cards-swipe li'),
        overlay = $('#mobi-cards ul #mobi-card #mobi-card-overlay'),
        header = $('#mobi-cards-header li');
    if (choose) {
      overlay.last().addClass("overlay-yes");
      header.last().addClass("opacity-change");
      list.last().addClass("swiping-yes").one(animationEndEvent, function(){
        choose = false;
        list.last().remove();
        header.last().remove();
        index++;
      });
    }
    else{
      overlay.last().addClass("overlay-nope");
      header.last().addClass("opacity-change");
       list.last().addClass("swiping-nope").one(animationEndEvent, function(){
        choose = true;
        list.last().remove();
        header.last().remove();
        index++
      });
    }
    add();
  },1500);
}

var swipe = function(scope, element, attrs){
    Person.add(2);
    Person.add(1);
    Person.add(0);

   setTimeout(function(){
      animateMobi();
   }, 0);
};
return{
  restrict: 'EA',
  link: swipe,
};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything I'm reading says "forget jQuery exists" when you move to Angular.  Could you do most of what you're trying without invoking jQuery?

Comment: I could replace the code with regular javascript but i'm looking for a more simple solution. I was wondering if anyone else has solved this before

Comment: I know a lot of developers using angular are against JQuery, personally I dont have the slightest idea why. I naturally do things the angular way but having that script and using it from time to type to do things that jqlite doesnt provide and javascript is too complex I think its makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you need to inject the jquery before you do angular.
just move the jquery script to the top, then Angular will know to work with it